# How to take key and value in a CSV file for Kmeans clustering in Mahout

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mahout

I am trying to run Kmeans clustering on below set of data,

```
Name,Gender,Age,Drinks,Country
John,M,30,Pepsi,US
Jack,M,25,Coke,US
David,M,34,Pepsi,UK
Ted,M,37,Limca,CAN
Robert,M,23,Limca,US
Adrian,M,31,Pepsi,US
Craig,M,37,Coke,UK
Katie,F,23,Limca,UK
Nancy,F,32,Pepsi,UK
```

I want to cluster the data based on Drinks(pepsi,coke,Limca)and i am able to do it.But i want to retrive name also alongside clustered data.

the output i am getting is

```
0
1
2 
Limca belongs to cluster:0
Cokde belongs to cluster:0
etc.
```

here i want to get the names also.

while converting to sequence file i am taking key as drinks and value as the rest of text and converting to sparsevector and then running Kmeans clustering,the names are not printed.
can anybody point how i extract name from the clusters which are there in values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to convert {Pepsi, Coke, Pepsi, Limca} to something like {1001, 1002, 1001, 1003} and again convert back to original values.

But as mentioned in one of the answers, just getting a group by drinks may not be a clustering job, it's just an SQL query. if your problem is more complex than grouping then you can try the approach that I mentioned in above Paragraph.

Comment: :Thank u for answer,I didnt get exactly your answer.I have a 50k records from social media data,as sample given above.I want to cluster them,so that there should be clusters of various drinks.eg:a cluster of pepsi.is this is right problem of clustering in mahout.

Comment: if the problem is simple like, group the users based on drink, just use a database query instead of clustering. clustering would be needed for a complex thing like forming clusters based on multiple features like age, gender, group etc. OR if your dataset is too scattered unlike a defined set like {PEPSI, COKE, etc}.

Comment: thanks,i was able to cluster by taking multiple features,thanks for the pointer..

Answer (score 0):

K-Means operates on vector spaces.

It absolutely needs to able to compute *means*.

But what is the mean value of `{Pepsi, Coke, Pepsi, Limca}`?

Sorry, you are trying to use a hammer, but you don't have a nail!

If you want to **group** data by their drink, this is not a clustering task.

Maybe try a Hadoop based SQL system. Because apparently you want to perform a classic SQL operation: `GROUP BY Drinks`

Oh, and your question is off-topic for stackoverflow. You are *using* Hadoop, but you are not posing a *programming* question!

Comment: how do i calculate mean in this.i have a records of 50,000 from social media,i want to cluster them,can you explain what clustering output may be after applying kmeans.Basiclly i converted the csv file to seqfile and then to sparsevetcor to act as input to mahout clustering.

Comment: You don't want to cluster them with k-means. You want to **group** them with SQL. Mahout is the wrong tool!

Comment: :Thanks for your suggestion ,now i am taking many parameters in arriving at clustering in mahout.